# How do I Split a file using Java program with one common String?

Tags: java

I have a .csv file with different countries weather data in which I have to split data into different  csv where country = India one .csv should be created with name row.csv if country other than India it should create as output.csv Please help since Iam a beginner unable to resolve even afgter several attempts.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class weather {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try 
        {
            String Country =null;
            String India = null;
            String s;
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\pratap\\Downloads\\weather1.csv");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            
            if (Country != India)
            {
                FileWriter  fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\pratap\\Downloads\\output.csv" , true);
                while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    fw.write(s);
                    fw.flush();
                }
                br.close();
                fw.close();
                System.out.println("file copied");
            }
            else
                
            {
                FileWriter  fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\pratap\\Downloads\\row.csv" , true);
                while((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    fw.write(s);
                    fw.flush();
                }
                br.close();
                fw.close();
                System.out.println("file copied");
            }
            
        }               
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't know . Say no what you have edited in the code

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting this to do: `if (Country != India)`  It looks like you've essentially skipped the step of reading the data from the CSV file and examining its contents.  A quick Google search for something like "java read csv file" finds a variety of examples.  At a high level, you'll want to separate the steps of reading and writing.  First read all of the records into an array of objects.  Then you're done with the original file.  Then loop over the array and, depending on the values in that object, append one file or another.

Comment: Don't use "==" or "!=" to compare Objects. Instead you use the `equals(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you don't seem to be even close. I'm not going to write this for you, as it sounds like a homework assignment, but I'm going to nudge you.

It sounds like you have one big file, and you're trying to pull out only the data for a single country, something you might be able to do with:

```
grep "India" < input.csv > output.csv
```

Clearly, that's probably an insufficent regular expression, but it sounds like that's what you're trying to code.

What you're going to need to do as a basic approach:

1. Open the input and output files
2. Loop, reading one line at a time.
3. For each line, determine, "Is this line for India?"
4. If so, write to the output file
5. Close both files and you're done.

As I don't know the structure of your data, I don't know exactly how you'll determine if a particular line is for India. That may complicate that particular step, but maybe not.

But for that step, I'd write a method:

```
bool isForIndia(const std::string & inputLine)
```

You'll have to extract out the country portion, Parsing CSV files can be a pain in the butt, though, so this is the hardest part of the entire problem.

Most of this is easy, however, if you follow the structure outlined.